# onKeyPress show Textarea box

Tags: javascript, event

OnKeypress is not working when i click on input type field its not showing inputtextarea.

```
<input type="Text" onKeyPress="myFunction()" styleClass="slds-input" value="enter email" id="intag"/>

 <apex:inputTextarea cols="100" rows="10"  id="textareaMsg" value=" {!msgbody}"/>

 <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById('textareaMsg').show();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: you need to specify entire component path if you use `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

This might help. This worked for me >

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="Text" onKeyPress="myFunction()" styleClass="slds-input" value="enter email" id="intag"/>

<apex:inputTextarea cols="100" rows="10"  id="textareaMsg" value="{!msgbody}" style="display:none" styleClass="testtextarea" />

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
  alert('key press working');
  $(".testtextarea").show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: only alert message is showing not the textarea

Comment: @cloudZigZag, have you added the script above, it is jquery which must be added to make it work!

Comment: yes added directly and in static resource as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `onkeypress` event occurs when the user presses a key (on the keyboard). In your case use `onclick` event. Use `style.display = 'block'` instead of `show()`. Javascript `querySelector` is more recommend than jquery `$`.

```
<apex:page>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            debugger;
            document.querySelector("[id*='textareaMsg']").style.display='block';
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <input type="Text" onClick="myFunction()" value="enter email" id="intag"/>

        <apex:inputTextarea cols="100" rows="10"  style="display:none"  id="textareaMsg"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```